# SHGetFolderPath': identifier not found

Tags: c++, winapi, directx

I am doing sample using DirectX 9 On Vs 2008/windows7.
I am getting error.

1>------ Build started: Project: VideoCapture, Configuration: Debug Unicode Win32 ------
1>Compiling...

1>VideoCaptureDlg.cpp
1>.\VideoCaptureDlg.cpp(169) : error C2065: 'SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT' : undeclared identifier
1>.\VideoCaptureDlg.cpp(169) : error C3861: 'SHGetFolderPath': identifier not found
1>.\VideoCaptureDlg.cpp(173) : error C2065: 'SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT' : undeclared identifier
1>.\VideoCaptureDlg.cpp(173) : error C3861: 'SHGetFolderPath': identifier not found
1>.\VideoCaptureDlg.cpp(1025) : warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'int' to 'WORD', possible loss of data
1>.\VideoCaptureDlg.cpp(1180) : error C2065: 'SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT' : undeclared identifier
1>.\VideoCaptureDlg.cpp(1180) : error C3861: 'SHGetFolderPath': identifier not found
1>.\VideoCaptureDlg.cpp(1184) : error C2065: 'SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT' : undeclared identifier
1>.\VideoCaptureDlg.cpp(1184) : error C3861: 'SHGetFolderPath': identifier not found

I have added shlobj.h and shell32.lib as well still it is showing the same error.

I tried changing value of following macro in stdafx.h file based on Windows 7 and Internet Explorer 8 but it is showing conflict "C1189: #error :  _WIN32_WINNT settings conflicts with _WIN32_IE setting"

// Refer to MSDN for the latest info on corresponding values for different platforms.

```
#ifndef WINVER // Allow use of features specific to Windows XP or later.    
#define WINVER 0x0501 // Change this to the appropriate value to target other versions  of Windows.    
#endif    

#ifndef _WIN32_WINNT // Allow use of features specific to Windows XP or later.     
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0601 // Change this to the appropriate value to target other versions of Windows.    
#endif      

#ifndef _WIN32_WINDOWS // Allow use of features specific to Windows 98 or later.     
#define _WIN32_WINDOWS 0x0410 // Change this to the appropriate value to target Windows Me or later.    
#endif    

#ifndef _WIN32_IE // Allow use of features specific to IE 6.0 or later.    
#define _WIN32_IE 0x0800 // Change this to the appropriate value to target other versions of IE.    
#endif
```

Any Suggestion for this Issue will be helpfull.

Comment: stdafx.h Yeah I am setting up before any include file

Comment: Moved comment to answer based on what triggers that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Issue is resolved the problem.
I just changed the Preprocessor setting under Project Properties--> c++->

Before it was
_WINDOWS;WINVER=0x0400;DEBUG;_DEBUG;_WIN32_WINNT=0x400;WIN32;UNICODE

I changed it to
_WINDOWS;WINVER=0x0600;DEBUG;_DEBUG;_WIN32_WINNT=0x600;WIN32;UNICODE

Answer (score 2):

Is the code block from MSDN or your `stdafx.h`? I would just set the macros with no messing about with conditionals (you want to override previous settings). Also ensure you are setting them before any includes (especially `windows.h`).

Looking at where the error message comes from (line 263 of `sdkddkver.h`):

```
#if ((_WIN32_WINNT < _WIN32_WINNT_WIN2K) && (_WIN32_IE > _WIN32_IE_IE60SP1))
#error _WIN32_WINNT settings conflicts with _WIN32_IE setting
#endif
```

you are *not* setting these macros in the way you think you are.

**EDIT** (as per comments):

I would *start* my `stdafx.h` file (and ensure that is *always* the first header; this is needed for effective pre-compiled headers as well):

```
#define WINVER 0x0601     // Kernel 6.1 == Windows 7/Server 2008 R2
#define _WIN32_WINNT WINVER
#define _WIN32_IE 0x0800  // IE8

#define NOMINMAX          // Don't define min and max (prefer C++ lib)
```

Comment: See!My Problem is  this error "error C3861: 'SHGetFolderPath': identifier not found".I searched the net there i found changing the value of these macro according to target system solves the problem.Thats why I changed the value and that is giving conflict.any suggestion for original error

Comment: @DeadMg what will be value for the macro.OS is Windows 7,IE is IE 8